# Finding limits superior and inferior of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limsup-and-liminf

Find the limits superior and inferior of the following sequences:
note:
"For a set, those are the infimum and supremum of the set's limit points, respectively. "

$a_n=\frac{n}{n+1} \sin{\frac{2n\pi}{4}}$

and

$c_n=1+2(-1)^{n+1}+3(-1)^{\binom{n}{2}}$
detailed help appreciated, because i do not know much

Comment: Can you write down the definition of limit superior and limit infimum and give it a try. Tell us what did u try?

Comment: but as far as i know i have to consider two diffrent subsequences for odd and even number, i do not know how to properly pick them up

Comment: Why don't you write down the definition in your question itself as a note. And then we can give a hint.

Comment: You should begin by understanding the sequences. Computing $a_n$ and $c_n$ for small $n$, say up to $8$, will be a good start. You should notice a pattern there …

Comment: right $c_n$ (6,-4,2,0) for number 1 to 4 but what about the solution? how to check the limits? could you explain me the method of solving such things?

Answer (score 1):

For the first sequence $\frac{n}{n+1} \longrightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $sin(2n \pi /4)$ fluctuates between 1 and -1

therefore limsup = 1 and liminf = -1

for the second sequence the supremum is 1 + 2 + 3 = 6 
the infimum is 1 - 2 -3 = -4

as the terms subjected to n are either 1 or -1 hence the simple upper and lower bounds

hope this helped